# how to check createSpyObj properties have been accessed

Tags: jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I am trying to figure out how to assert that properties created using `createSpyObj` have been accessed and I'm running into a brick wall.

See [this StackBlitz spec](https://stackblitz.com/edit/jasmine-testing-crcqqf?file=src%2Fidentity.spec.ts):

```js
describe('spyObjectTest', () => {
  it('should create a spy object and assert it was accessed', () => {
    const spyObj = jasmine.createSpyObj(
      'spyObj',
      {},
      {
        x: 'foo',
        y: 'bar',
        z: 'fubar',
      }
    );

    // Spy object is accessed here...
    console.log(spyObj.x, spyObj.y, spyObj.z);

    // I get this useless error. how is x not a spy?
    // Error: <toHaveBeenCalled> : Expected a spy, but got 'foo'.
    // Usage: expect(<spyObj>).toHaveBeenCalled() (line 5180)
    expect(spyObj.x).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(spyObj.y).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(spyObj.z).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

All I want to do is check that these properties, which should be spies, have been accessed. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, those properties are not spy objects but they are properties that are instance variables of the class or object. Spy objects are functions or methods and we can only use `toHaveBeenCalled()` on these.

What I would do is assert that the instance property in question got updated with these properties.

So if the code is:

```
this.x = theSpyObj.x;
```

The assertion can be:

```
expect(component.x).toBe('foo');
```